# PHP MySQLi isn't letting me alter a table (adding a new column)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Well thats pretty much it.

This is my query:

```
$query = 'ALTER TABLE permissions ADD '.$name.' INT NOT NULL DEFAULT \'0\'';
```

Where $name is already checked to exist with only lower case alpha letters, and not more than 20 length. Im just starting this out with very simple names.

The next 4 lines of code after that one are:

```
if($stmt = $db -> prepare($query))
{
    $success = $stmt -> execute();
    $stmt -> close();
    if(!$success)
        echo 'ERROR: Unsuccessful query: ',$db->error,PHP_EOL;
}
```

And I get back, every time

```
ERROR: Unsuccessful query:
```

And no error message. Is there a way to get more error messages so I can see what is failing? I can add new columns through phpmyadmin, but that really doesnt help me at all.

The $db is fine, i do lots of stuff before and after this one section. It is only adding new column to the table that fails.

- side question: prepare() rejected my query every time when i tried to make those 2 variables, the $name and the 0 value as  ? ? prepared statement values. Thats why they are in the real query and not bound later. If i could change that too I would like that.

Comment: Have you tried just `if ($db->query($query))` and scrapping the `prepare`?

Comment: that was it. i just had it left in there because of the old way of preparing it. 

Now that the query went through i got my error message, my user account did not have alter/drop permissions.

Do you think it is safe to query like this and not use prepared statements? This is literally the only place in my entire site where i do not prepare the query.

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace;

```
$db->error  to  $stmt->error
```

And put this before the close().

Answer (score 0):

worth checking you're not trying to use a column or table name that is 'reserved'. for example you cant have a col called 'lon' or 'host'